# Gradient in gradient?

Tags: css, webkit

Ok, I don't know if this is possible, just something wrong with my code...

So, I try to make a linear gradient within a gradient?

`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9DB2F0 0%, #9DB2F0 40%, -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 0%, yellow 100%) 40%)`

If possible, please tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or which browser it's possible in.

Comment: @Josh Didn't like my "Thank you :D"?

Comment: Don't take it personally.   [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552/157574)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradients are [image values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images), not [color values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color). Since gradients in CSS3 only make use of color stops, you can't nest them like that.

You'll want to find a gradient or image editor that can help you visualize what the final gradient would look like (because I don't know what you want it to look like), and that could possibly generate the corresponding single linear gradient for you.

From what I see, though, it looks like a multidirectional gradient. In that case, you'll either want to use [layered backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) (with one gradient per layer), or even an actual image instead.

Comment: @Truth: Yes, that was the one I was looking for but forgot the link. Thanks!

Comment: This distinction is a little more clear when using `background-image` rather than `background` to apply a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @BoltClock answer a few tricks you can play with:

- layered backgrounds as he stated in his answer. It's done with multiple background "images" (gradients). Each one can be controlled via:

  ```
  background-position: left center, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  ```

  if you've 2 images/gradients you want to style.
- gradients added to `:before` and `:after` pseudos. You can size and position these pseudos where you want (and you'll have to: absolute positioning, a bit of `z-index` to layer them between main background and actual content, etc). See for example a previous answer of mine and the fiddle: [Showing two different gradients as a background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046033/showing-two-different-gradients-as-a-background-using-css/11046122#11046122)

  It seems you can't add gradients via `content: url() url()`, only images (any valid value for url()). And what is added via `content` can't be controlled as a real background (repeat, position) so it wouldn't be the most versatile method even if it worked.